# CI: Querying two tables in the model, explode

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array, resultset, explode

i'm thinking about this for days now and don't come to grasps (since i'm relativley new to MVC and CI). I'm not even sure whether this is an issue with MVC, MySQL or arrays.

**Situation: 2 MySQL tables**

1. Table *data*: id, title, list
2. Table *values*: id, name

Querying the *data* table results in an array like the following (excerpt):

```
[4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [title] => Foo                
            [list] => 1,2,3,4,6,14
        )

[5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [title] => Bar                
            [list] => 2,6,9,12
        )
```

The field *list* contains comma separated values that correspond to some IDs of the *values* table like

```
[3] => Array
            (
                [id] => 12
                [name] => 'value12'                
            )
```

What I try to do for each row is:

- take the *list*-values & explode it into an array
- check with the result set from the *values*-table (via in_array() method)
- return the name values of the IDs if
- **include it somehow into the main result set** (e.g. as a 2-dimensional array):

  [5] => Array (
                  [id] => 4
                  [title] => Bar
                  [list] => Array (
                                     [0] => value6
                                     [1] => value12
                                     ...
                                  )
               )

My naive approach so far was to

- run a query on each of the 2 tables
- compare the 2 result sets via in_array

My main problem (while trying to strictly separate model, controller and view): How can I include the name field from the values-table in the "main loop" of the *data* table result set?

```
if($q->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $data[] = $q->result_array();
    foreach ($q->result() as $row)
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

If I use the following (cumbersome) approach i naturally get a new item each time:

```
foreach ($q->result_array() as $row) 
{
    $data[]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data[]['title'] = $row['title'];
    $data[]['list'] = $row['year'];
}
```

Since this is a MySQL database I see no way to do the explode and the comparison in SQL (with LIKE or something else).

Any hint, even a simple link to an info bit, is highly appreciated.

Thanks a trillion!

fab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a many-to-many relationship between lists and list values.  The conventional way to model this in a relational database is to create a joining table.  So I'd structure your schema like this.

```
lists : list_id, title
values : value_id, name
list_values : list_id, value_id
```

`list_values` is the joining table.  It links lists with values.

To build a list you could have the following functions in your model

```
function build_list($list_id)
{
    $list = $this->get_list($list_id);
    $list->values = $this->get_list_values($list_id);
    return $list;
}

function get_list($list_id)
{
    $sql = 'select * from lists where list_id=?';
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($list_id))->row();
}

function get_list_values($list_id)
{
    $sql = 'select v.value_id, v.name
        from list_values lv
        join values v on v.value_id=lv.value_id
        where lv.list_id=?';
    return $this->db->query($sql, array($list_id))->result();
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. Any time you're thinking about storing a comma-separated list of IDs in a column of a table, it's a strong signal that you're likely doing something wrong.

Comment: You guys are absolutely right. many-to-many-relationships always with a join table, of course! thanks a lot.